# how to change screen size from the webview itself?

Tags: electron

I have a function that is being called once the user hover the window. Is it possible to change the width of the window? this is my function:

```
function resize() {
    console.log('resize');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible to get access to the renderers `BrowserWindow` API. Simply include the remote module and get the current window, this will allow you to do everything you can from the main process.

**Example:**

```
let { remote } = require('electron')
let win = remote.getCurrentWindow()


// Access to the renderers BrowserWindow API
win.setBounds({
    width: 1000
})


win.getBounds()
// Object {x: 240, y: 192, width: 800, height: 600}
```

Reference: [`BrowserWindow` API documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.28.0/api/browser-window/)

Comment: Or a bit easier to just resize: `win.setSize(width, height[, animate])` whereas animating parameter is optionally expressed by [ ]

Comment: how do you change `minWidth` with `remote`??